# How to interpret k=1 when summing over k? Is there something wrong with this equation?

Tags: machine-learning, self-study, document-term-matrix

I am having a hard time understanding the following equation to do with document clustering.

Is there something wrong with it?

$$\ln \left(\prod_{n=1}^N \sum_{k=1}^K p\left(x_n \mid z_n, k=1\right) p\left(z_n, k=1\right)\right)$$

In pseudo code I initially want to read this as

```
The natural log of
  The product of (for each n)
    The sum of (for each k)
      The joint probability of
        The (data variable given the latent variable) and the first k
        Multiplied by the joint probability of the latent variable and k being 1
```

But then why would we enumerate over K?

For example if k=K and K !=1

Is there a more concise way to write the equation?

[Update]
GPT advises

$$\ln \left(\prod_{n=1}^N \sum_{k=1}^K p\left(x_n \mid z_n, k\right) p\left(z_n \mid k\right)\right)$$

[Update]

The full question is
[image: on document cluster model]

The answer is
[image: Answer]
[image: Answer more information]

[Update]

From my course notes I understand that $z_i=k$ and $k \in \{1...K\}$ and it represents the class label for the ith document.

Comment: Can you give a source of the equation? From the first look, $k=1$ seem to make no sense, but in the light of some context (i.e. text around it), I might be willing to change my view on it.

Comment: Thank you I posted the complete question and answer. At first I thought I was just not understanding the notation convention.

Comment: One more question: I am missing the definition of $z_n$ in the text. I would assume that this is the cluster to which document $n$ belongs. Can you confirm this? I will then turn my comments into an answer.  
If $z_n$ is indeed the cluster, the correct equation would be $\mathrm{ln}\left(\prod_{n=1}^N\sum_{k=1}^Kp(x_n|z_n=k)p(z_n=k)\right)$

Comment: Thank you. Yes . I updated the question.

Comment: I am in same boat as @Broele that k=1 does not make sense as it stands

Answer (score 1, accepted):

###### Summery:

The correct equation (in this way of notion) would be
$$\mathrm{ln}\left(\prod_{n=1}^Np(x_n)\right)=\mathrm{ln}\left(\prod_{n=1}^N\sum_{k=1}^Kp(x_n|z_n=k)p(z_n=k)\right)$$

This is a direct application of the law of total probability, which (roughtl) states that given an event $A$ and a finite partition $B_k$ of the sample space, the probability can be partitioned as follows:
$$P(A) = \sum_k P(A\cap B_k)$$

###### Why split it this way?

In mixture models, we typically do not model the total density (here $p(x_n$)), but for each part/cluster individually. So we define the distribution for each cluster individually, here given by:
$p(x_n|z_n=k)$.

Typically, this is easier to model and the total probability is given by the sum shown above. In case of your question we can define $p(x_n|z_n=k)$ for each cluster:
Each cluster $k$ has it's own probability $\mu_{k,w}$ that a given word $w$ occurs at a given position in the document. Under the assumption that all words are independent, a given document that consists of the words sequence $w_1,w_2,...w_M$ gets the probability
$$p(x_n|z_n=k)=\mu_{k,w_1}\cdot\mu_{k,w_2}\cdot\ldots\cdot\mu_{k,w_M}$$, which can be compressed into
$$\prod_{w}\mu_{k.w}^{c(x_n,w)}$$ if $c(x_n,w)$ just counts how often $w$ appears in $x_n$.

###### About the question

With this in mind, the question that you posted asks for $p(x|\mu)$, which deals with a single sample $x$ and omits the index $n$. Given $\mu$ here means, for a given probability vector $\mu$. Since we have one $\mu_k$ for each cluster $k$, this notion also omits the index $k$. Hence, we can see $p(x|\mu)$ as a short version of $p(x_n|\mu_k)$. An even better version would be $p(x_n|z_n=k)$ since $\mu_k$ is only relevant if document $x_n$ belongs to cluster $k$.

In this light the answer to the question would be:
$$p(x|\mu) = \prod_{w}\mu_{w}^{c(x,w)}$$
The answer you scanned and posted is including this into the computation of the total likelihood, while the question only asked for this piece of it.

###### The notion

From a probability theory point of view, this is a strong shortening of the correct notion. You typically need to distinguish between random variables and observed values / values they could take. This would lead to the equation

$$\mathrm{ln}\left(\prod_{n=1}^Np(X_n=x_n)\right)=\mathrm{ln}\left(\prod_{n=1}^N\sum_{k=1}^Kp(X_n=x_n|Z_n=k)p(Z_n=k)\right)$$
In machine learning literature, where the observations and the random variables are often names the same (except upper/lower case), it is common to shorten the notion to the one we have seen in the summery above.

###### The versions from the question

###### Original

$p(z_n,k=1)$ will be either p(z_n) (for $k=1$) or 0 (for $k \not= 1$). Note that $k=1$ is not a probabilistic event that might either occure with a certain probability, but a binary statement, that is either true (i.e. $p(K=1)=1$) or false (i.e. $p(k=1)=0$)

###### GPT

It shows that you should not trust GPT without checks.
First GPT produces also the machine-learning-community-type shortcut equation (which is totally fine), but this only works if implicitly you could define a longer probability-theory-style equation. But $p(z_n|k)$ only makes sense if there would be an implicit random variable corresponding to $k$. We do not have this, so $p(z_n|k)$ just looks like a ML-style equation, but has not meaning (of course you are free to define a meaning for this notion. It would just differ from the common notions)

Comment: Thank you. The actual question is asking for a formula of $p(x|\mu)$ yet that is not mentioned in the answer. Is the answer missing something? Also the original answer includes $\Phi_k$

Comment: Actually, I was not 100% sure what your question was. What I see is that you asked if something is wrong with the equation $p(...k=1)$ so I focussed on that question. Please let me know what you are missing. I will later extend my answer.

Comment: Thanks I am having trouble understanding the full question that my course asked about and the answer provided. Now I am understanding that the text of the provided answer incorrectly uses k=1. I wonder if the rest of the provided answer is correct or not.  I note it is different from your answer. It also looks different to what the question seems to be asking for.

Comment: I extended my answer (for this time). But please note that it is not liked, here, if someone extends and broadens the question (from "Is there something wrong with it?" to _explain what I scanned_). Try to be more specific next time and split such questions in multiple questions, each being more specific.

Comment: I get it. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

To answer your question regarding why we enumerate over K, it's because the equation considers the possibility of assigning a document to any of the K clusters. The sum over k accounts for all possible cluster assignments, allowing for the calculation of the joint probability of a document belonging to any cluster.

Comment: Thanks but my question is about how to interpret k=1 when enumerating over k. surely if it equals 1 then we are not enumerating. Thus it must be able to be worded better.